# Minimal Betti numbers of simply-connected threefolds with trivial canonical class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, calabi-yau

By a threefold, I mean a compact complex manifold of dimension three.

For a simply-connected threefold with trivial canonical class, its Betti numbers satisfy:
$$b_2 \ge 0, b_3 \ge 2.$$

I am wondering whether there is such a threefold with those minimal Betti numbers. Precisely,

> Is there a simply-connected threefold  with trivial canonical class and  Betti numbers $b_2 = 0$, $b_3 = 2$?

Note that such a threefold cannot be projective.

Comment: How about the Hopf manifold $S^3 \times S^3$?

Comment: @Nick L: Hopf manifolds are diffeomorphic to $S^{1}\times S^{2n-1}$. I guess you are thinking of the [Calabi-Eckmann manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi–Eckmann_manifold), but their  canonical class is  not trivial.

Comment: Topologically any simply connected threefold with $b_2= 0$ is a connected sum $k(S^3 \times S^3) \# Q$ where $Q$ is a rational homology sphere. Lu and Tian showed in "The complex structure on a connected sum of $S^3\times S^3$ with trivial canonical bundle" that $25(S^3 \times S^3)$ carries a complex structure with trivial canonical. I don't know if smaller examples have been found.

Comment: @Aleksandar Milivojević: 
Could you give a reference for your statement "Topologically any .... homology sphere"?

Comment: In their subsequent paper "The complex structures on connected sums of $S^3\times S^3$" Manifolds and geometry (Pisa, 1993), 284–293, Sympos. Math., XXXVI, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1996, Lu and Tian construct complex structures with trivial canonical bundle on all $k(S^3\times S^3)$ for $k\geq 2$.

Comment: @user69559 This follows from Theorem 1 in Wall's "Classification Problems in Differential Topology. V".